# Windows: Finding application that set environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Is there a way on Windows to trace the changes from applications or scripts to environment variables on startup?

I changed an environment variable in the System->Advanced->Environment Variables dialog but its value is reset when I reboot my computer (I am an administrator on my machine). I'd like to track down the application that changes this variable.

Comment: Changes made to the environment variables using that method should be permanent.  If the changes revert on the next restart, you're probably changing something integral to Windows, like the value for `ProgramFiles`.  That's an example of something that *can* be changed, but must be changed in more than one place (usually in the registry).  It might help if you could tell us which variable you're trying to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a n00b on Winders, but aren't environment variables always written to the registry?  Possibly look for a registry monitor?

Comment: You're right. I used RegMon and found the offending program. Thanks